# Is there a way to give prefrence to class I wrote over class in system namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote class named `ConfigurationManager.cs`, that sightly changes the original(built in) `ConfigurationManager`.

To access my class:

```
ConfigruationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

To access the system class:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

What I want to do is that if someone uses the system class it should still access the one in my class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this, for a good reason: if what you want were possible, users would be able to run all sorts of nasty security attacks on unsuspecting .NET software.

For example, one could write a malicious library that returns invalid data, makes your program wait forever, or transmits the data about the calls that a piece of software makes to an external site. I am sure that serous hackers would be able to find many creative ways to exploit such possibility. So in short, the answer is "not possible".

Answer (score 5):

You can't force client code to use a specific type. If they write:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

There is *nothing* you can do about it, at least at run-time. You could write some static code analysis rules to notify you about any instances of that code, but thats about it.

Comment: +1.  There is something to be said about trusting the invoker to use the right implementation.  If you can't do that, after all, why are you distributing your software?

Comment: @DavidL Indeed. The user of the library should (and does) always get the final say.